# Count the number of times a rule is declared - SWIProlog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I'd like to count the number of times a certain rule has been declared.

For example "my_rule/3":

```
        my_rule(1,A,B) :- A is 1, B is 2.
        my_rule(2,A,B) :- A is 2, B is 3.
        my_rule(3,A,B) :- A is 3, B is 4.
        my_rule(4,A,B) :- A is 21, B is 1.

        ?- count_myrule(C).
        C = 4.
```

Note that i want to count a rule, and not a fact. In the previous example semantics of rules does not matter, i just want to understand if it is possible to count how many times I have declared a certain rule.
Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `clause/2` to get the definitions of all clauses for a predicate. The first argument is the clause head you're interested in, the second argument is the body. The body will be `true` if the clause is a fact (or if it's written as a "rule" with just `true` as its body).

For example, given:

```
foo(a, b).
foo(b, c).
foo(C, D) :-
    foo(D, C).
```

we get:

```
?- clause(foo(X, Y), Body).
X = a,
Y = b,
Body = true ;
X = b,
Y = c,
Body = true ;
Body = foo(Y, X).
```

The first two answers are for the two facts (`Body` is `true`), the third answer is for the rule. So to get rules only:

```
?- clause(foo(X, Y), Body), Body \= true.
Body = foo(Y, X).
```

To count the number of rules, you can use any approach that counts the number of solutions of this query. For example, use `findall/3` to collect a list of the solutions and take the length of that, or use SWI-Prolog's `aggregate/3`.

**Edit:** Note the comment by Paulo Moura on portability to other Prolog systems.

Comment: It works, what a nice solution!! Thank you very much.

Comment: Note that, in most Prolog systems, you can only call `clause/2` on dynamic predicates. This solution works in SWI-Prolog (which the OP declares is used) assuming the `protect_static_code` is set to `false` (its default but changeable value).

Comment: Thanks, I added a note in my answer pointing to your comment.